# Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Sales Matrix"} SELENIUM and JAVA - JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath

I have this button with collapsible moves:

[image]

It contains this info:

```
<strong data-bind="css: {'admin__collapsible-title': collapsible,
                      title: !collapsible,
                      '_changed': changed,
                      '_loading': loading,
                      '_error': error}" class="admin__collapsible-title">
            <span data-bind="i18n: label">Sales Matrix</span>
            <!-- ko if: collapsible --><span class="admin__page-nav-item-messages">
                <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message _changed">
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-icon"></span>
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-tooltip" data-bind="i18n: 'Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved.'">Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved.</span>
                </span>
                <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message _error">
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-icon"></span>
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-tooltip" data-bind="i18n: 'This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.'">This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.</span>
                </span>
                <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-loader">
                    <span class="spinner">
                       <!-- ko repeat: 8 --><span data-repeat-index="0"></span><span data-repeat-index="1"></span><span data-repeat-index="2"></span><span data-repeat-index="3"></span><span data-repeat-index="4"></span><span data-repeat-index="5"></span><span data-repeat-index="6"></span><span data-repeat-index="7"></span><!-- /ko -->
                    </span>
               </span>
            </span><!-- /ko -->
        </strong>
```

I have tried many ways to click on that button but nothing seems to be working for me.

I tried:

```
a) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales Matrix')]")).click();. 


b) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Sales Matrix']")).click();.
```

I think it is the locator issue and was thinkin abput using some JavascriptExecutor but don't really know how to achieve that in this case.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add for reference, there are different ways to click.

```
// Click using Action
Actions actions = new Actions(browser);
actions.click(tempWebElem).build().perform();

// Click using JS
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", tempWebElem);

// Click using WebElement
driver.findElement(tempElem).click();

// Click using Send Keys
driver.findElement(tempElem).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

On our project, I have these lines in a nested try-catch, so that it can try other approach if the locator issue is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by doing this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales Matrix')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Thank you!